# Updating a literal and gridView simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, sql, gridview, literals

Is there any way to have a literal update when the "update" button in a gridview has been hit? 
The literal is populated with the sum of all the values in one column of the gridview and when the gridview is updated I also want the literal to immediately update. The gridView is being populated from a sql server.
My literal's code behind is:

```
   protected void litBalance_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string queryString =
            "SELECT SUM(AuthorizationAmount) AS Balance FROM dbo.CPSTransaction WHERE (ApplicationIDPrimary = '" + Request.QueryString["WSUID"] + "')";
        using (SqlConnection connection =
                   new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OrientationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                litBalance.Text = reader["Balance"].ToString();
            }

            // Call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

and it's .net is:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litBalance" runat="server" oninit="litBalance_Init"></asp:Literal>
```

I have tried using a label instead of a literal and giving the gridview's edit button and the label the same ValidationGroup but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting your literal edit code inside the RowCommand event handler for the GridView?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I just figured out that I should have stuck it in the RowUpdated and it worked great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting the code in the gv_RowUpdated method:

```
protected void gvPaymentDetails_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{

    string balanceQueryString =
        "SELECT SUM(AuthorizationAmount) AS Balance FROM dbo.CPSTransaction WHERE (ApplicationIDPrimary = '" + Request.QueryString["WSUID"] + "')";
    using (SqlConnection balanceConnection =
               new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OrientationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand balanceCommand =
            new SqlCommand(balanceQueryString, balanceConnection);
        balanceConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader balanceReader = balanceCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (balanceReader.HasRows)
        {
            balanceReader.Read();
            litBalance.Text = balanceReader["Balance"].ToString();
        }

        // Call Close when done reading.
        balanceReader.Close();
    }

}
```